# Send text to specific li in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a number of li items in a ul. I need to add all of the li items to an array, then loop through the array and sum a value that is in each li.

The value is for the number of hours that item will take. So item one might be 2 hours, item two might be 5 hours.

For every 7.5 hours, I need to add 1 day to the day field in each li. So item 1,2 and 3 will display day 1. Items 4,5,6 and 7 will display day 2 etc.

Here is what I have so far:

list array:

```
var list = document.getElementById("dropArea").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Number of Hours:

```
var hrsArray = $("#sortable2 li").find("#hrsSpan").map(function () { return $(this).text() }).get();
var lengthArr = hrsArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < lengthArr; i++) {
    hrsArray[i] = hrsArray[i].replace("Hours - (", "");
    hrsArray[i] = hrsArray[i].replace(")", "");
}
```

And here is were I count the total number of hours. I can send "1" to the day span in each li, but I can't figure out how to look at the li's on an individual basis:

```
//Add all the hrs together to get the total
for (var i in hrsArray) {
    total += hrsArray[i];
    //alert(list[i].toString());

    //Object found at this point, need to figure out how to send text to day span in it.
    if (total / 7.5 <= 1) {
        $('#sortable2 li').find('#day').html('1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#sortable2 li').find('#day')
```

This creates a set with all the matched objects, to retrieve a specific object use .get(index).
http://api.jquery.com/get/

```
$('#sortable2 li').find('#day').get(i).html('1');
```

To avoid rebuilding the set on every iteration, I would store it in a variable outside of the loop.

```
//Add all the hrs together to get the total
var $dayFields = $('#sortable2 li').find('#day');
for (var i in hrsArray) {
    total += hrsArray[i];
    //alert(list[i].toString());

    //Object found at this point, need to figure out how to send text to day span in it.
    if (total / 7.5 <= 1) {
        $($dayFields.get(i)).html('1');
    }
}
```

EDIT:

A better way to approach this would be to loop over each li instead of an array of hours:

```
$("#sortable2 li").each(function() {
    $(this).find("hrsSpan"); // This selects the hours field
    $(this).find("day"); // This selects the day field in the same li
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$('#sortable2 li').find('#day').html('1');` you lose the jquery object on the find. You would need to wrap it in the $() again. Here's a simpler way to do it without having to use find.

```
$("#sortable2 #day").html(1)
```

Heres an example of it working http://jsfiddle.net/9nutmuvm/

Comment: Excellent, so is there anyway to select the li item dynamically? This would send 1 to every list item

Comment: This would grab each li in the ul and add `1`inside the li `$("#sortable2 li").html(1)`

Comment: Yeah but I dont want to put '1' in every li, it will change depending on the total hours